# SQL Server selecting data as array from two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, node.js

I have a database in which there are two tables `tableA, tableB`. Now for each primary id in `tableA` there may be multiple rows in `tableB`.

**Table A** primary key (ServiceOrderId)

```
+----------------+-------+-------+-------------+
| ServiceOrderId | Tax   | Total | OrderNumber |
+----------------+-------+-------+-------------+
| 12             | 45.00 | 347   | 1011        |
+----------------+-------+-------+-------------+
```

**Table B** foreign key (ServiceOrderId)

```
+----+-------------+---------------------+----------+-------+------+----------------+
| Id | ServiceName | ServiceDescription  | Quantity | Price | Cost | ServiceOrderId |
+----+-------------+---------------------+----------+-------+------+----------------+
| 39 | MIN-C       | Commercial Pretreat | NULL     | 225   | 23   | 12             |
+----+-------------+---------------------+----------+-------+------+----------------+
| 40 | MIN-C       | Commercial Pretreat | NULL     | 225   | 25   | 12             |
+----+-------------+---------------------+----------+-------+------+----------------+
```

Is there a way in which I can fetch the values as an array of multiple rows of tableB with single row of tableA. Because when I am saving to database I am using temp table to save multiple rows of tableB with single row of tableA.

Query I am using

```
SELECT  
    ordr.*,
    info.*
FROM 
    tblServiceOrder as ordr
JOIN 
    tblServiceOrderInfo as info ON ordr.ServiceOrderId = info.ServiceOrderId
```

But above query is giving two rows for each `ServiceOrderId`. I am using node api to fetch data. I want something like;

```
Object:{
        objectA:{id:12,tax:45.00:total:347,ordernumber:1011}, 
        objectB:[
           {id:39,servicename:'MIN-C',description:'Commercial Pretreat',Quantity :NULL,Price:225,Cost:23,ServiceOrderId:12 },
           {id:40,servicename:'MIN-C',description:'Commercial Pretreat',Quantity :NULL,Price:225,Cost:25,ServiceOrderId:12}
          ]
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several solutions. The first one is to use your SELECT, but with adding ORDER BY ServiceOrderID and when data are converting to object, to use the first row only in the loop for new ServiceOrderId from *ordr* table and add every row for the data from *info* table.

Other possibility is to select data from *ordr* table only and for every row to make another select by ServiceOrderId from *info* table. This solution should not be used for huge tables.

Comment: It would more easy to understand if you include query.